# Renaming a variable in a loop in R

Tags: r, plyr

I'm trying to rename several variables by attaching a string from a loop:

```
df <- data.frame(net_low_mptc=1:3,   net_medium_mptc=4:6, net_high_mptc=7:9)
x<-c("low","medium","high")


for(lvl in x) { 
rename(df, c(sprintf("net_%s_mptc", lvl) = sprintf("bill_%s_F", lvl))) }
```

The error is caused by the sprintf expression:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"for(lvl in x) { 
rename(df, c(sprintf("net_%s_mptc", lvl) ="
```

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) Maybe use `dplyr::rename_` ?

Comment: sorry I don't follow this...

Comment: Add `dput(head(df_1))` to your post, so we can reproduce same data.

Comment: you can try `colnames(df) <- sub(paste0("net_(", paste(x, collapse="|"), ")_mptc"), "bill_\\1_F", colnames(df))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what he/she is trying to do:

```
library(plyr)

x <- c("low","medium","high")

for(lvl in x) { 
  df_1 <- rename(df_1, setNames(sprintf("bill_tdcv_%s_F", lvl), sprintf("bill_no_net_tdcv_%s", lvl)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:**

```
colnames(df) <- sub("net_", "bill_", colnames(df))
colnames(df) <- sub("_mptc", "_F", colnames(df))

colnames(df)
# [1] "bill_low_F"    "bill_medium_F" "bill_high_F"
```

I am guessing here, maybe try this:

```
x <- c("low", "medium", "high")
colnames(df_1)[colnames(df_1) %in% paste0("bill_no_net_tdcv_", x)] <- 
  paste0("bill_tdcv_", x, "_F")
```

You might be better off with regex solution, please provide your data.

Comment: you might get some unexpected result there if the colnames are not in the same order than x (e.g. you're risking replacing something with `high` by something with `low`)

Comment: done ;-) and probably `colnames(df) <- sub(paste0("net_(", paste(x, collapse="|"), ")_mptc"), "bill_\\1_F", colnames(df))` would do it